# Cannot find module error when running JS in terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js

It's my firt time using node today and I was faced with this issue. When trying to run hello.js in my terminal, I get this error :

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/antoinelafonta/hello.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
```

It's running fine when using the VsCode terminal.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please include from which directory and exactly how you ran this script.

Comment: You're probably not in the correct place when you try to run it